# Jenkins with SSH plugin throwing errors: unable to execute commands on remote server and unable to transfer files to remote server

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Using jenkins-ssh plugin, I am trying to connect to a remote server and deploy the changes from jenkins, trying to run the commands on server.

Build is successful. Jenkins log messages says that files are transferred but when I checked the server directory, I couldn't find any file.

After this transferring, it is trying to execute commands on server but it s failed to do that. I configured details like hostname, username, port, password and configured in "Manage Jenkins". Did test configuration as well, it is success.

But, at the end of logs it's throwing errors as given below. Can anyone please help me if you have some idea on these issues? What mistake I am doing, please let me know, I will correct it. It would be helpful to me. Thanks.

```
Total time: 3 seconds
[name of server configuration] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1043789630298533742.sh
+ ssh user@servername /bin/bash
(gnome-ssh-askpass:32106): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:  
Permission denied, please try again.
(gnome-ssh-askpass:32107): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:  
Permission denied, please try again.
(gnome-ssh-askpass:32119): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:  
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased).
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
SSH: Connecting from host [server]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [name of server configuration] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [name of server configuration] ...
SSH: Transferred 11 ( 7 + 3 + 1 ) file(s)
SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Your jenkins script is trying to run `gnome-ssh-askpass` to read either a password or a key passphrase, and this step is failing. How is ssh supposed to authenticate, through an ssh key or a password? How are you expecting ssh to get this password or passphrase which it needs?

Comment: SSH is authenticated using SSH private RSA key of remote server. Am not getting above gnome-ssh-askpass specific errors. Jenkins log says, all files are transferred including count (how many) but, when I go and check the server, files are not available. Its really tricky to understand it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing as admin through command line or you can give permissions to the path were it is trying to execute.
suggestion: try to run the command using sudo.

Comment: I tried to send data from jenkins server directly (putty) to remote server (linux), it works fine. I can see the file on server. But, when I try to do the same thing in jenkins using SSH plugin (Send files or execute commands over SSH before the build starts) it says files are transferred including how many files done. But on server, no files are available in the related path. Do you have any example how to run sudo in jenkins & where to run in jenkins? Please let me know.

Comment: Can i know how you have configured it in Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, I ran command in execute shell using jenkins without SSH. It works fine. Thanks.